# Azure Diagnostics in Azure sdk 2.7

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics, azure-sdk-.net

I cannot find the diagnostics.xsd schema for diagnostics in azure 2.7 version.It was available in earlier version.Can anybody point me where it is in 2.7 version?

Answer (score 1):

It is in the same place as SDK 2.6 - C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure.NET SDK\v2.7\bin\plugins\Diagnostics\schema.

Or is there a different file you are trying to find?

Comment: Thanks got it now ..in earlier versions before 2.6 it used be in seperate schema folder

Comment: How can i configure azure diagnostics if i don't want the storage account to be visible in non-encrypted format in configuration file
One way in which i can do is to enable diagnostics after deployment of package but will need to do this after every deployment.
any suggestions?